# Why doesn´t Excel function change cells for calcuation

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have the following function:

```
=SUMIF('Pivot'!$A$5:$A$51;'Projects Overview'!E4;'Pivot'!$B$5:$B$51)
```

I need it to automatically change `$B$5:$B$51` to `$C$5:$C$51`, `$D$5:$D$51`, etc. when dragging the function down to other rows.

I´m kinda lost - tried all types cell locking but didn't help.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want cell references to change when you drag the formula, don't anchor the values with $'s.  Also, dragging down through rows won't change column references.  You will need to add more detail to your question about what you're trying to do.

Comment: When you use absolute references `$` they don't change as you drag the function down. If you need to change rows while dragging down a column, just remove those.

If you need to change columns while dragging down a column, you'll need something to increment it, which gets tricky. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You are using absolute referencing with the `$`. This anchors the reference to that address only. No matter how much you drag or copy it, your formula is locked to `$B$5:$B$51`.

By removing the `$` you will be able to drag the formula to other cells and it will adjust automatically using relative referencing.

Keep in mind, Excel is not a mind reader. Depending where your formula is placed, it will adjust your formula in reference to surrounding cells and formula(s). Complicated formulas with off sheet references don't always drag well.

Comment: You answered the low-hanging fruit.  The question asks how to change column references when you drag down to other rows (unless that was a mistake by the OP in writing the question and he really meant for the example to change row references).